# Cannot get a message to display properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is some code form a program that has stumped me, so I am sure it is something easy I am overlooking. The "lblError" label is meant to display various messages depending on the circumstance. It displays "Please Enter User Name" and "Please Enter Password" like it is supposed to when a text box is empty. However, it will not display "User has successfully been added" when the user record is saved. everything works as planned, except this message. Can anyone point me I the right direction?

```
// Eventhandler for the AddUser Button
protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Declare variable
        bool isValid = true;
        lblError.Text = "";

        //Format forecolor of lblError.Text
        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        // Validate UserName.Text 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtUserName.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
        {
            // Format textbox and return false boolean if no input
            txtUserName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text += "Please Enter User Name! <br/>";
            isValid = false;
        }

        // Validate txtPassword.Text 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtUserPassword.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
        {
            // Format textbox and return false boolean if no input
            txtUserPassword.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text += "Please Enter Password! <br/>";
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            // If data is validated, save to database  and display message that it was successful  
            clsDataLayer.SaveUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"),
                                        txtUserName.Text,
                                        txtUserPassword.Text,
                                        ddlSecurityLevel.Text);
                Response.Redirect("frmManageUsers.aspx");
                lblError.Text += "User has successfully been added! <br/>";
                grdViewUsers.DataBind();             

        }
    }// End try block

    // Displays error message if invalid data is entered. 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblError.Text += "Please enter a valid data!";
    }
}// End AddUser Button Event Handler
```

Comment: assuming this label isn't on `frmManageUsers.aspx`, the problem is that you're redirecting prior to the label being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will never execute because you are doing a redirect. when you do a redirect, the page pretty much stops executing or finishes executing before actually redirecting. you maybe redirecting to the same page but then that means the page is "new" again thus anything you display previously will not show.

```
            Response.Redirect("frmManageUsers.aspx");
            lblError.Text += "User has successfully been added! <br/>";
```

remove the response.redirect if you are trying to stay on the same page

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Response.Redirect` to inform the client that it should go to a different page.  Once your ASP response reaches the client it will ask for a new page, at which point it starts all over again with none of the output the code above has generated.